# Issues with c++ thread memory leak on a simple thread when using join?

Tags: c++, multithreading, join, memory-leaks

I've written a program that features a main loop that kicks off threads at about 60 Hz.  I'm using std::thread to kick off the threads and I've played around a bit with join() and detach(), and for now I'm just using join until I figure out how to deal with this memory leak.

I've found that even with a very simple thread, with a very simple task, joined immediately and subsequently deleted immediately, when I view the executable in Task Manager, I still see the memory gradually increase.  When I comment out those three lines of code, the memory usage remains stable.

In essence, here's a stripped-down version of the code, pointing out those three lines in question:

```
void PrintStuff()
{
    cout << "Hi!\n";
}

void MainLoop::RunMainLoop()
{
    // Variable Definitions
    thread *LoopThread;

    ...

    while(true){

    ...

       if (SixtyHz[CycleCounter]){
       //Simplified for readability, but runs at 60 Hz

            /*********************************************
            * These three lines right here.
            * If I comment these out, the memory usage 
            * is stable!
            *********************************************/
            LoopThread = new thread{PrintStuff};
            LoopThread->join();
            delete LoopThread;

       }

       ...

       //Increment CycleCounter with appropriate modulo arithmetic
       CycleCounter = ...
    }
}
```

I'm using Code::Blocks with MinGW-w64, if that makes a difference.

Is std::thread just not up to the task?  Or is there anything I should be doing to reclaim those resources?  What gives?  Those lines are as simple as I could think to make them, and still I see a memory leak.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: just do `thread LoopThread;` instead of new/delte

Comment: Your "sixty hertz" thing is unrelated to whether threading leaks, and might leak itself if written poorly - why don't you remove it and just have a `while (true) { LoopThread = ... }` loop - see if that also leaks?  billz's suggestion is then a good sanity check for whether your dynamic allocation routines are responsible - if so, perhaps in some debug mode they accumulate records of allocations for leak analysis or something - check your docs or search specifically for new/delete leaks with MinGW-w64.

Comment: I have tried declaring the thread within the loop, without dynamic allocation, and there is still a memory leak.  After some Googling, I found an interesting discussion at the following link: [std::thread and memory leaks](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/32875609/)  It would appear to me that std::thread indeed just memory leaks.  For such basic functionality to have such a fatal flaw is really disappointing.  I guess I need to investigate other methods of creating threads...

Comment: Are you really creating and destroying a thread 60 times per second? That seems very excessive, especially on Windows where the thread creation overhead can be high. Why not use a single thread and send it a message (at 60Hz), then wait for a message in return indicating the work is done. In fact, if your main thread really is just waiting for the worker to do its thing, you can simply call `PrintStuff` without the thread and avoid all overhead.

Comment: I've never noticed a thread leak myself (also using mingw-w64 here, though with less extreme thread turnover), except with address sanitizer enabled (which isn't possible on mingw-w64 as far as I know). What's the threading model of your MinGW? I'm using POSIX.